# 3 websites hacked at the same time, how is that possible?

Tags: php, security

I have 3 of my sites hosted on the same dedicated server.

A hacker broke into `Site A` last week, using the security hole of an out-of-date editor, and uploaded a backdoor php script named `help.php` in one of the folders on Site A, and the path to the backdoor script was like `/home/siteA/public_html/readme/help.php`.

An hour later, he copied the backdoor script to folders on `Site B` and `C`, and had 3 backdoor scripts on my server: `/home/siteB/public_html/help.php` and `/home/siteC/public_html/help.php`.

My question is, how was that possible, considering the sites are assigned under different users.

Shouldn't all of his activities restricted within the site where the back door script was initially uploaded on `Site A`? How did he get the permission to access to folders on `Site B and C`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The directories are under control of the same user, however, also in control of those directories is the `www-data` user, which generally has the most access on the system, because it has to be able to access everyone's files to share them.

If the attacker managed to upload the script, they may have used it to run a command as the `www-data` user, allowing them to have access to the other sites as well.